# ansible can't find a python package even if it is installed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible, devops

Trying to use `docker-compose` within an ansible playbook using the `docker_compose` module. Note that I can successfully use the docker module in ansible but running into problems with `docker_compose` module. I'm using plaintext vars for testing locally, I use ansible-vault for storing secrets.

On the ansible documentation it explains that their docker-compose module only supports version 1 and 2 of docker-compose.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
---
version: "2.4"
services:
   my_demo:
       build: .
       networks:
          demo_net:
             ipv4_address: 172.0.1.2
       ports:
          - 8080:8080
       image: demo_image

networks:
    demo_net:
       driver: bridge
       ipam:
         driver: default
         config:
           - subnet: 172.0.1.0/30
             gateway: 172.0.1.1
```

Here is my `main.yml`:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: true

  vars:
    - ansible_sudo_pass: password
    - ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3

  tasks:
    - name: Docker compose
      docker_compose:
         project_name: docker_fhe_ansible
         project_src: .
         build: yes
      register: output

    - debug:
        var: output
```

Output:

```
PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Docker compose] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (Docker SDK for Python: docker (Python >= 2.7) or docker-py (Python 2.6)) on ubuntu's Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter, for example via `pip install docker` or `pip install docker-py` (Python 2.6). The error was: No module named 'docker'"}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The error is "no module named docker", I can verify python3 has the module:

```
john@ubuntu:~/Documents/docker-ansible$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import docker
>>> import ansible
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You state, you verified that those packages are present, but you can install packages in many ways which do not make them globally available. For example, you can install them in a virtualenv or for your user only.
If ansible tells you that it is missing those packages, it can't find them. You are running ansible as `root` on the machine (`become: true`), so you need to make sure those packages are available to `root`.
(Edit: This was actually the problem. The package was available for the user `john`, but not for `root`)

You are missing the `docker` module (and probably other requirements as well).
Install them at the beginning of your play using

```yaml
- name: ensure required pip-packages are installed
  pip:
    name: 
      - docker>=1.8.0
      - PyYAML>=3.11
      - docker-compose>=1.7.0
```

If you install them using a separate playbook, make sure to use `become: true` on that one as well, otherwise it will again be installed for your user only.

What I usually do when writing playbooks or roles is to make sure that all required packages are installed first. This means I would put the task in the same playbook/role that uses the `docker_compose` module. Like this, I'm sure that my stuff will work even if a colleague messes around on the machine and they can also use my code "as-is" without having to install something first.

Further notes:

- Always check the documentation for module requirements and install them before using the module. For example for the [docker_compose module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_compose_module.html#requirements).
- Also be aware, that you need to install them on the remote host, not the ansible-controller!
- Take a look at the [documentation of the pip module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pip_module.html) in case you are using a virtualenv.

Comment: I'm not missing the docker module though, refer to my question. I'm verifying those modules exist. If I run `pip3 show <module>` they all exist

Comment: Maybe you are running in a virtualenv or ansible is using a different version of python? Maybe those modules are installed locally (in your user's home directory) but not globally, so if you run python as root, it can't find them?
If ansible says, it can't find those modules, then they are missing.

Comment: @TecGuy94 try installing those packages the way I showed in my answer, and it will work

Comment: yeah so I installed the pip modules using your method successfully, there was no change in idempotency of the environment it detected the modules were there. I re ran my playbook with docker_compose with the same error unfortunately

Comment: @TecGuy94 Did you also use `become: true` when you installed them? Can you do `sudo /usr/bin/python3` and then `import docker`?

Comment: oh I didnt I'll give that a shot

Comment: I think that might be it! The playbook is running and the docker-compose task looks to be executing at least. The image its building is a few GB in size but I think that looks to have fixed it. Thanks very much!! Update your comment with become:true for an official answer :)

Comment: I updated your code for the complete version that solved my issue. Thanks again!

Comment: What I usually do when writing playbooks or roles is to make sure that all required packages are installed first. This means I would put the task in the same playbook/role that uses the `docker_compose` module. Like this, I'm sure that my stuff will work even if a colleague messes around on the machine and they can also use my code "as-is" without having to install something first.

Comment: Ah ok yeah that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Failed to import [...] on ubuntu's Python /usr/bin/python3 [...] error was: No module named 'docker'
> ```

However you are able to import the module from your local Python interpreter.

Check the `python3` you are using to test is indeed `/usr/bin/python3` (with `which python3` for example). If not, you can use Ansible [`ansible_python_interpreter`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html) to specify the proper Python interpreter.

Comment: `john@ubuntu:~/Documents/docker-ansible$ which python3` <br>
`/usr/bin/python3.`

Comment: `ansible-playbook local.yml -e "ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3"`  results in the same error